# Enable AWS lambda Python to Connect to MySQL via SSH Tunnelling

Tags: python, mysql, amazon-web-services, ssh

This is the first time I am trying to connect to database (WP in this case) via SSH with lambda function.  I can connect to this DB via SSH from client(mySQL Workbench).  From other posts it looks like SSHTunnel is a good option to use in lambda function.

I created a package installing sshtunnel, created layer, and attached layer to function.  Used post from Gabe Olokun (https://www.linkedin.com/pulse/add-external-python-libraries-aws-lambda-using-layers-gabe-olokun) that has worked successfully for other packages.

When I run a basic function, I get the following error:
"Unable to import module 'lambda_function': No module named '_cffi_backend'"

I have two import statements.  pymysql works with no issues.  I followed same process to create that package, create layer and attach.

```
import pymysql.cursors
from sshtunnel import SSHTunnelForwarder
```

Using Python 3.9

I have searched and come up with nothing.  Appreciate any help.  #rookie :)

Comment: Is it not possible to run the Lambda in the same VPC as the database? Is the database even running on AWS?

Comment: @MarkB I am running a multisite WP instance using AWS lightsail and that is the database I am trying to connect to.  I guess I am not 100% sure but was assuming that the Lightsail WP instance would need SSL connection like my client does.  When my webpage pull data from the DB I do connect directly as it is local.

Comment: So you are trying to connect a Lambda function to a database running on a Lightsail instance?

Comment: By the way, your current error is due to the `SSHTunnelForwarder` library needing statically linked binaries that are not being bundled in your Lambda deployment file.

Comment: @MarkB that is correct: Lambda function connected to Lightsail instance.

Comment: @MarkB I ran `pip install sshtunnel -t .` to install and create package.  Shouldn't that install all dependencies or do I miss a step there?

Comment: No, your sshtunnel package requires some binaries, like whatever `_cffi_backend` is. It's a much more involved process to set that up: https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/lambda-linux-binary-package/ Alternatively you could deploy a Lambda docker image.

Comment: I highly suggest you move the database off the Lightsail server and over to RDS if you care about things like automated recovery and backups of your database. Then your Lambda function could run in the same VPC as the database. Alternatively, stick with Lightsail for everything and build whatever it is you are trying to do with a Lambda function as just a regular python script that runs on the Lightsail server.